# Remove all skus from woocommerce database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

We have asked this question before with out success, hope someone can help this time.

We have a site with over 1200 sku's that are wrong and we want to delete them all without affecting the products.

We are running the latest version of WP.

Is there a quicker way to do this via the db in phpmyadmin.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `Update wp_postmeta set meta_value ='' WHERE meta_key = '_sku'` in phpmyadmin and it will reset all _sku without affecting the products.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, was going to be so time consuming to do it manually.